# Callback returning object and property of object is not called as expected

Tags: javascript, callback

I decided to experiment with a mix of callbacks and promises. In my context, I'm not using actual promises but the promise notation of "then". I am trying to call a function that has a callback which returns an object. That object returns an object with a function that calls the function inside the then() method attached to the first call. Below is my code:

```js
function step1(arg,callback) {
 //do stuff
  var obj = {key:"value"};
  callback(obj);
}

function step2(obj) {
 //do something to obj
  obj.key2 = "hey";
  return {
   andthen: function(callback) {
     callback(obj);
    }
 };
}

function step3(obj) {
  //modify obj more
  console.log(obj);
}

step1('arg1',step2).andthen(function(obj) { step3(obj); });
```

This code results in an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'andthen' of undefined. `Since step1('arg1',step2)` is returning an object, why can't javascript call the "andthen" property of the object? I realize Javascript is asyncronous but my understanding is that `.andthen(function(obj) { step3(obj); })` would wait until `step1` is finished.

Comment: `step1` doesn't return anything at all *(except `undefined`)*, so you're mistaken on that part, and it can't be chained.

Comment: Also, perhaps this a contrived example, but this code doesn't do anything asyncronous, so what's the point? Just call the three methods in order.

Comment: Actually `step1('arg1', function(o) { step2(o).andthen(step3) });`

Comment: @bhamlin Let's say step1 was a function that does something asyncronous. Would "andthen" activate before the code completes (giving undefined property) or would it activate after the code completes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the `return` statement in the `step1` function before the `callback(obj)` statement:

```
function step1(arg,callback) {
    //do stuff
  var obj = {key:"value"};
  return callback(obj);
}
```

As a general remark, in JavaScript, last statement of the function is not automatically it's return value, `return` keyword has to be stated explicitly.